# In Javascript is it possible to get duplicate keyboard input and how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, event-listener

I am trying to learn Javascript and my first project is the game 2048. I got everything to work but there is one problem that happens when I give keyboard inputs very quickly after each other. I believe it's related to how I detect keyboard input, here is the main function:

```
processing = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (processing) {
        return;
    }

    processing = true;

    let direction;
    if (event.code === 'ArrowRight' || event.code === 'KeyD') {
        direction = "right";
    } else if (event.code == "ArrowLeft" || event.code === 'KeyA') {
        direction = "left";
    } else if (event.code =="ArrowUp" || event.code === 'KeyW') {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (event.code == "ArrowDown" || event.code === 'KeyS') {
        direction = "down";
    } else {
        processing = false;
        return;
    }
    moveAll(direction)
        .then(changed => {
            if (changed) {
                spawnTile()
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return checkForMoves();
        })
        .then(moveIsPossible => {
            if (!moveIsPossible) {
                doGameOver();
            }
        })
        .finally(() => {
            processing = false
        });
});
```

The idea is that when an input happens, the `processing` flag is set to true and no more input can be received until everything is updated. However, only when giving inputs very quickly, problems occur and it has to do with the animations that run (I don't think that code is relevant but I can post it if needed).

It seems to me that this happens when two inputs get past the first `processing` check at the same time, which of course leads to problems. What I am asking is, is that a plausible explanation, and what would be the fix?

I used to have the animations work with event listeners for the `transitionend` event, and when giving very quick inputs it would just freeze as the `transitionend` would never be fired. I switched to timeouts for the animations which avoids the freezing but still leads to glitchiness.

Comment: The browser runs event handlers for one event at a time.

Comment: But then any idea why it would go wrong with quick inputs?

Comment: What does the behavior does the `processing` variable guarantee and does it work without this check?

Comment: No, it doesn't work without it. It ensures that the next movement is not started before the last one is finished, so all the board is updated and the sliding animations are finished.